# How can I swap Asp.Net Views in a Multiview using a slider effect

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net MultiView contained within an UpdatePanel, and switching between the different views is done using AsyncPostBackTriggers and calling Update for the UpdatePanel on the server side. I'd like to have the old View slide out while the new View slides in, but I have no idea how to do this. I realize I'll have to use jquery, but what event do I wire up to? Is this even possible with these server side controls? 
Switching to Mvc is not an option, I'm stuck having to use these non-MVC yesteryear asp.net server controls.

Comment: Those are serverside controls, you dont have controls over them. You can look at the generated html source and see how you may be able to hack into it

Comment: The purpose of a `MultiView` is to render only one `View` on any give postback.  There is no code to act upon on ready state.  But...because you are using UpdatePanels you *may* be able to simulate it by sliding out the current view before the async postback, then slide in the new view on async ready